# Fatal error while calling row() method in view file: "Call to a member function row() on a non-object"

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

I am trying to get the result of my query to the view but it always ends in an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object in

I am trying to search a customer info by customer id and trying to get the result to the view.

This is my view:

```
<?php echo form_open('home/cari_id');
?>
<table width='34%' align='left'>
    <tr>
        <td width="54%" align="left">ID Pelanggan</td>
        
        <td width="36%">
            <?php echo form_input('id',set_value('id'));?>
            <?php echo form_error('id');?>
        </td>
        <td width="10%">
            <?php echo form_submit('submit','Cari');?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table> 

<br /><br />

<table width="68%" align="left">
    <tr>
        <td width="17%" align="left">Nama</td>
        <td>
            <?php   
                $row = $record->row();
                $nama1 = array(
                         'name' => 'nama',
                         'maxlength' => '100',
                         'size' => '50',
                         'style' => 'width:120%');
                echo form_input($nama1,$row->nama);?>
            <?php echo form_error('nama');?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td align="left">Alamat</td>
    <td>
        <?php 
            $alamat1 = array(
                        'name' => 'alamat',
                        'rows' => '5',
                        'cols' => '3',
                        'style' => 'width:200%');
            echo form_textarea($alamat1,$row->alamat);?>
        <?php echo form_error('alamat');?>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left">Golongan</td>
        <td width='29%'>
            <?php 
                $gol1 = array(
                        'name' => 'gol',
                        'maxlength' => '100',
                        'size' => '50',
                        'style' => 'width:40%');
                echo form_input($gol1,$row->golongan);?>
            <?php echo form_error('gol');?>
        </td>
        <td width="10%" align="left">Tarif</td>
        <td width="44%">
            <?php 
                $tarif = array(
                'name' => 'tarif',
                'maxlength' => '100',
                'size' => '50',
                'style' => 'width:30%');
                echo form_input($tarif,$row->tarif);?>
            <?php echo form_error('tarif');?>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here my controller method:

```
public function cari_id()
{
    $this->auth->restrict();
    // mencegah user mengakses menu yang tidak boleh ia buka
    $this->auth->cek_menu(4);
    
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('id', 'ID Pelanggan', 'trim|required');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('nama','Nama','trim'|'required');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('alamat','Alamat','trim'|'required');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('gol', 'Golongan', 'trim|required');
    //$this->form_validation->set_rules('tarif', 'Tarif', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters(' <span style="color:#FF0000">', '</span>');
    $id_pel = $this->input->post('id') ;
    //$data1 = $this->usermodel->get_list_bayar_pel($id_pel);
    //$data=$data1->row();
    $data1 = $this->usermodel->get_list_bayar_pel($id_pel);
    $data['record'] = $query->result_array();
    $this->template->set('title','Input Pembayaran | POS Application');
    $this->template->load('template','admin/input_pembayaran',$data);
}
```

My model method:

```
function get_list_bayar_pel($id)
{
    $this->db->select('b.name as nama, b.address as alamat, c.nm_gol as golongan,d.rate_value as tarif');
    $this->db->from('account_t a, account_nameinfo_t b, golongan_t c, (select rate_value from rate_t a, golongan_t b where a.id_gol = b.id_gol) d');    
    $this->db->where('a.id_account = b.obj_id');
    $this->db->where('a.id_gol = c.id_gol');
    $this->db->where('a.id_account = "'.$id.'"');
    $result = $this->db->get();
    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

write this one in your controller

```
$data['record'] = $query->row();
```

and in view remove the 
php code write

```
 <?php   

                $nama1 = array(
                         'name' => 'nama',
                         'maxlength' => '100',
                         'size' => '50',
                         'style' => 'width:120%');
                echo form_input($nama1,$record->nama);?>
            <?php echo form_error('nama');?>
```

in model

```
$result = $this->db->get('tablename')->row();
```

Answer (score 0):

$record isn't returning a single row it is returning a collection either use current($record)->row() or fetch a single row.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller you are fetching multiple rows

```
$data['record'] = $query->result_array();
```

It should be

```
$data['record'] = $query->row();
```

and in view give $row = $record; instead of $row = $record->row();

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you used row() function for retrieving data in the view, meanwhile it has been fetched in the controller using this :

```
 $data['record'] = $query->result_array();
```

Just use one of them (in the Controller) :

```
$data['record'] = $query->result_array();
```

or

```
$data['record'] = $query->row();
```

And then process the array in the view

Hope it helps :)

Note : 
- I would recommend you use result_array() to retrieve the data into array

Answer (score 0):

- I do not endorse old-skool comma-JOINs in SQL -- they make the query less intuitive to human readers.  Use explicit keyword when needing to JOIN tables.
- Your query should not be passing the `$id` as a substring of a where condition as a matter of best practice.
- Returning a query's result object to other layers is probably not advisable. Yes, it affords the flexibility in different controller methods to populate the data structure in a granular way, but it will also lead to "fat controllers" (doing too many operations) and reduces data consistency throughout the project. Instead, in the model methods signature, explicitly data-type `$id` as an integer and the return value as an array (and use `->result_array()` if you want an array of arrays).
- In your controller, you declare `$data1` to receive the model's return value, but then try to pass the data from `$query->result_array()` (bear in mind, `$query` is not a declared variable in this scope) to `$data['record']`. The model method's return value should be passed directly to `$data['record']` with no intermediate variable declarations.
- All data that hits the view layer should be fully prepared. At most, the view should be performing minor formatting of data, but that's all.  It's only job should be to present data.
- Since `bayar_pel` means "pay for the mop" according to Google, I have no idea what your model method does.  If it will return multiple rows, then return a 2d array; if it will always return a single row or `null`, then use `row()` or `row_array()` (according to your preference).

Model Method:

```
function get_list_bayar_pel(int $id): array
{
    return $this->db
        ->select([
            'b.name AS nama',
            'b.address AS alamat',
            'c.nm_gol AS golongan',
            'd.rate_value AS tarif',
        ])
        ->join('account_nameinfo_t b', 'a.id_account = b.obj_id')
        ->join('golongan_t c', 'a.id_gol = c.id_gol')
        ->join('rate_t d', 'b.id_gol = d.id_gol')
        ->get_where('account_t a', ['a.id_account' => $id])
        ->result_array();
}
```

Controller Method:

```
public function cari_id()
{
    $this->auth->restrict();
    // prevent users from accessing menus that they cannot open
    $this->auth->cek_menu(4);

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('id', 'ID Pelanggan', 'trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters(' <span style="color:#FF0000">', '</span>');

    $id_pel = $this->input->post('id') ;
    $data['record'] = $this->usermodel->get_list_bayar_pel($id_pel);
    $this->template->set('title', 'Input Pembayaran | POS Application');
    $this->template->load('template', 'admin/input_pembayaran', $data);
}
```

In your view, if your model method returned `result_array()` (an empty array or an array of arrays), then `$row = $record->row();` should become:

```
if (!$record) {
    exit('Record not found for supplied id');
} else {
    $row = $record[0];
    // ... your form fields ...
}
```

If your model method returned `row()` (an flat object or null), then `$row = $record->row();` should become:

```
if (!$record) {
    exit('Record not found for supplied id');
} else {
    // don't bother declaring $row, just use the $record object to access its properties
    // ... your form fields ...
}
```